# parse this JSON and create a new div for each object

Tags: jquery, json

I get this JSON from a PHP script, and I'm currently at this point with the code. What I would like to do, is for each object, insert the response into a div.

For example I would like to insert the "sentences" into div id="sentences" and the title into div id="title", and I would like to prepend, or create a new one for each new response.

Any tips on how to proceed?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("warming up...");
    $.getJSON("response.php", function( data ) {
       console.log("got JSON");
         for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        console.log(obj.title);
        }
    });
});     
</script>
```

Here is the JSON response:

```
{ "sentences" : [ "The big irony behind the scorched-earth Republican offensive against President Obama’s health-care law is that its expansion of coverage to the uninsured would benefit House districts represented by Republicans nearly as much as those represented by Democrats.",
      "Regardless of what other provisions they consider harmful, that posture unavoidably means House Republicans are seeking to “protect” a surprisingly large number of their constituents from the right to obtain health insurance with federal assistance.",
      "Recently released census data show that, on average, the share of residents without insurance is almost as high in districts represented by House Republicans as in those represented by Democrats.",
      "Slightly more Republicans (107) than Democrats (99) represent districts where the uninsured percentage is above the national average.",
      "Massachusetts has the lowest percentage of uninsured due to its state-run health insurance, which has been in place since 2006."
    ],
  "summaryId" : "W76Z7a",
  "title" : "Where Are the Uninsured Americans Who Will Benefit From Obamacare?"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) because `data` is not an array, it is an object.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("warming up...");
    $.getJSON("response.php", function (data) {
        console.log("got JSON");

        $.each(data, function (key, obj) {
            console.log(key, obj)
            $('<div />', {
                id: key,
                text: obj
            }).appendTo('body')
        });
    });
});
```